# Turn a PSD file into a transparent jpg

Tags: psd

I have a PSD file (but not Photoshop), I turned it into a jpeg using some website, but it turns out the jpeg isn't transparent.

I've literally never used Photoshop before in my life, so I'm not sure what to do. I managed to somewhat solve the problem with MS paint and paint.net, but the quality suffered.[image]

Above is the jpeg, not transparent

[image]

Here is what I managed to do, transparent (open in a new tab), as you can see, the quality isn't the same and there's a very tiny white bar at the bottom of the green text.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'd upload the PSD but I don't think I can on SE.

Comment: Hi, JPG files do not support transparency. You should use PNG format instead.

Comment: The second one is a PNG - JPEG does not support alpha-channels (aka transparency).

Comment: Thank you, I turned it into a PNG instead and it worked.